# Where does UiDevice dumpWindowHierarchy create file?

Tags: android, dump, android-uiautomator, ui-testing

I've been trying to obtain the layout of a screen (the logical content, including the resource_ids of the views in a screen) using UIAutomator but with no luck (so if anyone has the answer to this without using dumpWindowHierarchy I'd also appreciate).

I try running device.dumpWindowHierarchy(filename) in several ways none of which seem to work:

file creation:

```
File f = new File("dump.xml");
```

or

```
File f = new File("/data/local/tmp/dump.xml");
```

or

```
File f = new File(Environment.getDataDirectory().getPath() + "/local/tmp/dump.xml"); //I saw somewhere that the documentation was wrong and this was the actual place where it dumped the file
```

and I tried combining these with this two options:

```
device.dumpWindowHierarchy(f.getName());
```

or

```
device.dumpWindowHierarchy(f.getAbsolutePath());
```

With any of these combinations

```
if(f.exists())
```

always returns false (after running the dump method).

It doesn't seem to be an error with permissions as the takeScreenshot method seems to create the file in /data/local/tmp.

I've also tried running:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("dump");
```

but it gives the following error:

```
Error running exec(). Command: [dump] Working Directory: null Environment: null
```

I'm running this in

```
public class MainTester extends UiAutomatorTestCase{
     public void testTry(){
          UiDevice device = getUiDevice();
          //code to open the app

          //code explained above
     }
}
```

Comment: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("uiautomator dump /data/local/tmp/dump.xml");`

Comment: When running `uiautomator -- help` in the device shell, it says the default location for dumped XML is `/storage/emulated/legacy/window_dump.xml`.

Comment: when I run this line in my testApp, it always return "killed": Runtime.getRuntime().exec("uiautomator dump /data/local/tmp/dump.xml"); Could someone explain me why?

Answer (score 2):

you could get the view in this way:

```html
final String dumpXml = "dump.xml";
final File dump = new File(new File(Environment.getDataDirectory(),
"local/tmp"), dumpXml);
dump.mkdirs();
if (dump.exists()) {
    dump.delete();
}
UiDevice.getInstance().dumpWindowHierarchy(dumpXml);
```

Comment: Why you put "if (dump.exists()) {dump.delete();}"? It does not make sense to first mkdirs and then delete it

Comment: How can I change the saving directory of dumXml. I tried to change the directory, but I did not find the dumped xml file. I can only find the dumped xml file in /data/local/tmp/local/tmp/ directory